# Rails route: adding helpers methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am coding an API in rails, and the following scheme appears multiple times in my routes.rb:
(The goal is to link existing devices resource to users one.)

```
  resources 'devices', controller: 'users_devices',     only: [ 'index', 'destroy' ] do
    post on: :member,                                   action: 'create'
  end
```

I would like to have a "route extension" that would allow me to do this:

```
relation 'devices', controller: 'users_devices'
```

Much more readable and since I have 5 times this same 'boiler plate' code, it would simplify the routes.rb

But... How can i code this "relation" method ?

Comment: That's a super ugly bit of indenting. There's no good reason to put the "action" way, *way* out to the right like that.

Comment: Unrelated with the question, but to answer you, it's to group the http verb and route on left side and controller methods on right side.

Comment: I know *what* you're doing, I'm trying to tell you that you shouldn't be doing it. Rails is a world of strong conventions, and inventing your own which run counter to Rails' won't do you any favours.

Comment: I didn't know there was a convention on routes indentation! Could you point me a resource that could help me to learn it ? Thanks

Comment: This is less specifically Rails and more specifically Ruby: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide